# Disabling a 'Rule' before sending an email, and then re-enabling the Rule after the email was sent

Tags: vba, outlook, rules

I have an "Oh Shi-" rule, that delays the delivery of my emails by 5 minutes.
I disable this rule whenever I want the email to reach the recipient as fast as possible. The rule is re-enabled after the email is sent.

The macro is triggered via a button on the "Message" ribbon.

Sometimes the email will be sent right away.

Sometimes the email will sit in the outbox.  If I check under **Options Ribbon → Delay Delivery**, there is a 5 minutes delay set. The 5-min rule should have been disabled.

Below is my code:

```vb
Sub OhShi()
    Dim olRules As Outlook.Rules
    Dim olRule As Outlook.Rule
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim blnExecute As Boolean


    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application

    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to fast-send the email?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "The OhShi- rule is being disabled!")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Cancel = False
    ElseIf answer = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        Cancel = True
    End If


    If Cancel = False Then
        'disable the rule
         
        Set olRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules
        Set olRule = olRules.Item("Delay Delivery 5min")
        olRule.Enabled = False
        If blnExecute Then olRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True
        olRules.Save
         
        'check if rule was indeed disabled
        If olRule.Enabled = False Then
            'send active email
            Set objItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
            objItem.Send
        Else
            MsgBox "The script failed successfully!", vbCritical
        End If
        
        'reenable the rule
        olRule.Enabled = True
        If blnExecute Then olRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True
        olRules.Save
        
        Set olRules = Nothing
        Set olRule = Nothing
        Set objItem = Nothing
        
    End If

End Sub
```

I have just tried to remove the part of the code which re-enables the Rule, but the Rule is still being applied to the email. After the code is run I can verify now that the rule was indeed disabled, but it still gets applied to the email.

Comment: I would suggest the objItem.Send is acted upon asynchronously, so by the time the rule is re-enabled, the item may not still have been sent and then gets caught? Do you find it's larger messages which fail to get through? you may find a delay function useful which checks `objItem.Sent` for `True` between the objItem.Send and rule re-enablement works

Comment: good idea @Tragamor . Unfortunately I have just tried to remove the part of the code which re-enables the Rule, but the Rule is still being applied to the email. After the code is run I can verify now that the rule was indeed disabled, but it still gets applied to the email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If disabling the rule is ignored, possibly something is not synchronized when the item is sent.

Waiting before sending may increase reliability.

```vb
Sub disableRule()

    Dim olRules As Rules
    Dim olRuleName As String
    Dim olRule As Rule
    
    Dim objItem As Object
    
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim msg As String
    
    Set olRules = Session.defaultStore.GetRules
    olRuleName = "Delay Delivery 5min"
    Set olRule = olRules.Item(olRuleName)
    
    Set objItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
        
    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to fast-send the email?", _
      vbOKCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, _
      "The " & olRuleName & " rule is being disabled!")
    
    If answer = vbOK Then
    
        ' disable the rule
        olRule.Enabled = False
        olRules.Save
        Debug.Print vbCr & "Rule disabled."
         
        ' If synching is the cause
        Dim waitTime As Long
        Dim delay As Date
        
        ' If it can takes minutes, occasionally failing to send fast may be preferable.
        waitTime = 3    ' in seconds - adjust as needed
        Debug.Print vbCr & "Wait start: " & Now
        
        delay = DateAdd("s", waitTime, Now)
        Debug.Print "Wait until: " & delay
        
        Do Until Now > delay
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        Debug.Print "Wait end..: " & Now
        Debug.Print "At least " & waitTime & " seconds delay to allow a synch someplace."
        
        ' send active email
        objItem.Send
        Debug.Print vbCr & "objItem.Send"
        
        msg = "Item sent with disabled rule possiby synched."
        Debug.Print msg
        MsgBox msg, vbInformation
        
        olRule.Enabled = True
        olRules.Save
        Debug.Print vbCr & "Rule re-enabled."
        
    Else
        msg = "Item not sent."
        Debug.Print msg
        MsgBox msg, vbInformation
        
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That seems to be working for now, I will give it a try for a few more days before I set as the correct answer.
I am kinda of skeptical because I have tried this same approach, but using the Sleep function, and that didn't work, so I am wondering if this Delaying approach is different somehow, and that's why now it seems to work.
Anyway, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: this has been working flawlessly for the last couple of days, thanks for the solution @niton !